# access variable value inside controller from ngResource in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I make a Get call to an API, inside my controller I want to access the values of that object how can I do it?, if I use data binding I can view the value of the variable within the object.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",["ngResource"]);
app.factory("myAppFactory",function($resource){
  return{
    Test: $resource("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:id", {id:"@id"})
  }
});
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope,myAppFactory){
  var productDetailServer = myAppFactory.Test.get({ id: 1 }, function () {
    });
    var aux=productDetailServer;
    $scope.variable = productDetailServer;
    console.log(productDetailServer);
    console.log("the website\n");
    console.log(aux.website);
    console.log("how do you access variable inside the response?");
    /*
    How can I do something like this:

    var website =productDetailServer.website
    website should access the website within the productDetailServer object but 
    all I get is undefined, how do I assign the website propierty from the object to the variable?
    Thanks

    */
});
```

But how can I access the value of the variables from the controller? Thanks

I made a Plunker to better explain what I meant:

https://plnkr.co/edit/lSsxdbgc5eRXzuIV64ND?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It returns a promise, you should use it.

```
myAppFactory.Test.get({ id: 1 }).$promise.then(function (data) {
  $scope.variable = data;
});
```

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZC97Y9pVcLy5PnzaXXOd?p=preview)

You should read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)